# Is it possible to compress a particular collection?

Tags: mongodb

This is the configuration of my MongoDB :

```
systemLog:
  path: "C:\\log\\mg.log"
  logAppend: true
  destination: file
storage:
  dbPath: "c:\\data"
  directoryPerDB: true
  engine: wiredTiger
  wiredTiger:
    engineConfig:
      cacheSizeGB: 1
```

How can I Instruct the MongoDB engine to compress one particular collection?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking about a particular collection I see two options for you.

1. You can use a settings of storage when you create collection:

   ```
   db.createCollection("your_collection", 
                       { storageEngine: {
                           wiredTiger: {configString: "blockCompressor=zlib"}
                       }})
   ```
2. OR you can compress your data on the side of application and store as binary. Probably it's better first to measure how much you will win in both cases.